# Парсер на Python. Как вытащить значение title с помощью xpath

Tags: python, парсер, xpath

Подскажите, как при помощи `xpath` выдернуть текстовое значение `title`?
Вот кусок сайта для примера.

```html
<a id="bx_3966226736_564931_pict"
   href="/catalog/polubotinki_i_mokasiny/p078_1u_bezh_polubotinki_muzhskie_39_44_8/"
   class="bx_catalog_item_images"
   style="background-image: url('/upload/resize_cache/iblock/93f/220_220_2/93fbbce7cd5fe0c3b38b5b9f24375804.jpg')"
   title="P078-1U беж Полуботинки мужские (39-44)/8">
</a>
```

Сейчас `xpath` выглядит вот так (скопирован с самого сайта):

```css
xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[2]/text()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[2]/@title')
```

`/html/body` — это начало **xpath** выражения, которое говорит о том, что мы начинаем с корня документа и переходим в тег **body**.

`/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]` — это последовательность тегов, которые мы проходим, чтобы добраться до нужного элемента. Мы переходим в третий `div`, затем еще раз в третий `div`, затем во второй `div`, затем в третий `div`, затем в третий `div` и, наконец, в первый `div`.

`/a[2]` — это указание на то, что мы хотим выбрать второй элемент `a`.

`@title` — это выделение атрибута **title** у элемента `a`.
Итого, данное **xpath** выражение находит второй элемент `a` на странице и выделяет его атрибут **title**.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Там проблема была в другом. Я на самом деле пробовал через @title  просто у меня выводилось не то. Проблема была в кодировке. За 2 дня обучения пытаюсь слишком много информации переварить.

Comment: Мой ответ помог или нужно еще что-то подсказать ? :)